# Set fallback font in gvim

Tags: gvim, microsoft-windows, font

gVim provides an option, `:h guifont`, to set the font of the gui window. Although it accepts a comma-separated list of fonts, it selects the first available font. If a symbol doesn't exist in the selected font, gVim does not fall back on the other fonts to render the missing symbol.

I realize this is the intended behavior, but seeing that the terminal vim is able to make smart choices (by dint of the terminal emulator), it's odd that the GUI version is dumber in font rendering, when the opposite should've been the case. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: The secret is precisely that TUI Vim doesn't concern itself with font rendering while GVim does. Where TUI Vim benefits from whatever the host terminal emulator uses under the hood. GVim is on its own, probably using some antiquated library.

Comment: @romainl makes sense. I'll keep this question open, in case the GUI gets an overhaul someday. Plus vi.SE doesn't have a similar question. This can be a tracking issue of sorts.